# Primefaces Push update fails in page

Tags: primefaces, push

I recently upgraded from Primefaces 4.0 to 5.0, and I'm not able to get my push messaging to work with 5.0.  My server is Glassfish 4.0, and browser is Firefox 29.0.1

I've reduced the problem to a very simple example, that follows the example in the user guide.  When I click on the button to send the message, it successfully is received by the endpoint, but I get a javascript error and the text isn't updated. Here is the  error:

the connection to ws://localhost:26293/pushtest/primepush/mytest?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.2.0-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&X-atmo-protocol=true was interrupted while the page was loading.

My page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"    >
    <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="send message" actionListener="#{testBean.sendMessage()}"/>

        <p:socket channel="/mytest" onMessage="handleMessage"  >

            </p:socket>
            <h:outputText styleClass="messageDisplay" id="test1" value="hello text"/>
    </h:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        function handleMessage(data) {                      
            $('.messageDisplay').text(data);
        }     // ]]>
    </script>

</h:body>
```

```
Backing Bean: 
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestBean {
    public void sendMessage() {
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println("sending message, now: "+now);
         EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();         
        eventBus.publish("/mytest", "complete "+now);        
    }
}

Push Endpoint: 

@PushEndpoint("/mytest")
public class PushEndPoint {
@OnMessage(encoders= {JSONEncoder.class})
public String onMessage(String msg) {
    System.out.println("received msg: "+msg);
    return msg;
}
```

}

Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>  
       <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>

Maven Dependencies: 

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```